# SpringBoot 2.2.1 groovyMarkupConfigurer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy

I have a SpringBoot application that was developed with JDK8 and was now ported to JDK11. I get the following exception at startup:

```
ERROR SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groovyMarkupConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/groovy/template/GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration$GroovyMarkupConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader(jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader,jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath) accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @2e3967ea
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at de.ff.jf.bftag.alarmmonitor.Main.main(Main.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader(jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader,jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath) accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @2e3967ea
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:189)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1.run(CachedConstructor.java:44)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.<init>(CachedConstructor.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getConstructors(CachedClass.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:218)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:228)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass(MetaClassRegistry.java:171)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:161)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:261)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:873)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:906)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:898)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToBoolean(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ASTTransformationCustomizer.findASTTranformationClass(ASTTransformationCustomizer.groovy:209)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:214)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ASTTransformationCustomizer.findPhase(ASTTransformationCustomizer.groovy:226)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:214)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ASTTransformationCustomizer.<init>(ASTTransformationCustomizer.groovy:180)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ASTTransformationCustomizer.<init>(ASTTransformationCustomizer.groovy:188)
    at groovy.text.markup.MarkupTemplateEngine.<init>(MarkupTemplateEngine.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.groovy.GroovyMarkupConfigurer.createTemplateEngine(GroovyMarkupConfigurer.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.groovy.GroovyMarkupConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(GroovyMarkupConfigurer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 15 more
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jxmapviewer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxmapviewer2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I have tried SpringWebStarter from 2.1.8 up to 2.2.1, I am always getting the same error.
I cannot use JDK8 again, since the computer has been updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and I am not willed to register at Oracle to download the JDK8 ;)

Has someone experienced this issue or does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You don't need to register with Oracle to download JDK 8. Binaries are freely available from https://adoptopenjdk.net.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your error is related to Java module system:

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader(jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader,jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath) accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @2e3967ea

Judging from the stack trace this is caused by Groovy so either your are using an old Groovy version that doesn't support JDK 9 or running code that imports `jdk.internal.loader` without declaring proper Java module access.

I'd start by checking that you have recent Groovy dependencies but a quick workaround would be to run the JVM with:

```
--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since this is a private project, your solution is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 6):

Exception arises in groovy autoconfiguration, so you can disable it in config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration.class})
```

or in property file:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration
```

Also in my case next properties resolved this issue:

```
spring.groovy.template.enabled=false
spring.groovy.template.check-template-location=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the below property as suggested by Alex worked for me.

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration